# Polar co-ordinates derivatives

Tags: derivatives, polar-coordinates, infinity

what does it mean by dr/dθ is infinity in polar co-ordinates? Please give me a mathematical proof. I specifically need to know what happens to r when dr/dθ approches infinity. r and θ are polar co-ordinates.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint : $r=\frac{x}{\cos\theta}\,,\frac{dr}{d\theta}=x\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}\,.$